# Hiding scrollbar on animating CSS

Tags: css

I've tried all the `overflow` types to no avail. As the sliding div slides right and zooms out, the horizontal scrollbar persists!

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
#slide {
    position: absolute;
    left: -40px;
    background: black;
    -webkit-animation: slide 5s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    animation: slide 5s forwards;
    animation-delay: 0s;
 zoom: 1.1;
 -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
 width: 100%;
 height: 400px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    100% { left: 40px; zoom: 1; -moz-transform: scale(1); }
}

@keyframes slide {
    100% { left: 40px; zoom: 1; -moz-transform: scale(1); }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="slide"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `transform: translateZ(0)` on the wrapper fixes the overflow problem - perhaps it has to do with the transformation creating a new stacking context.

**Live Demo:**

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;  
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
#slide {
    position: absolute;
    left: -40px;
    background: black;
    -webkit-animation: slide 5s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    animation: slide 5s forwards;
    animation-delay: 0s;
 zoom: 1.1;
 -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
 width: 100%;
 height: 400px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    100% { left: 40px; zoom: 1; -moz-transform: scale(1); }
}

@keyframes slide {
    100% { left: 40px; zoom: 1; -moz-transform: scale(1); }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="slide"></div>
</div>
```